# Android Bluetooth SPP Loss/Corrupted Data

Tags: android, performance, android-bluetooth, corruption, data-loss

I'm attempting to transfer a large file (2.7MB) from a server device to an android device via bluetooth using SPP. Upon connection, the android device reads the bytes available and store into a buffer of 2.7MB. I am using the variable "counter" (counting from 0 to 127) to verify the data.

To experiment, all data is correct if the server device outputs the file byte by byte. However, if the device outputs in packets of n bytes (e.g. 128 in this case), the data received on android was corrupted without any consistent pattern - it would incorrectly read values as 0s or 1s, but it always fixed itself at the start of the packet.

Any suggestions on how to prevent loss/corruption of data is greatly appreciated.

Receiving on Android device:

```
int imageSize = 2718720;
int counter = 0;
int totalByte = 0;

byte[] buffer = new byte[imageSize];

while (totalByte < imageSize) {
    int bytesAvailable = mInStream.available();
    int numOfBytesRead = mInStream.read(buffer, totalByte, bytesAvailable);
    for (int i = totalByte; i < totalByte + numOfBytesRead; i++) {
        if (buffer[i] != counter) {
            Log.d("BTDevice", Integer.toString(i) + ". read byte = " + Integer.toString(buffer[i] & 0xff) + " - Failed");
        } else {
            Log.d("BTDevice", Integer.toString(i) + ". read byte = " + Integer.toString(buffer[i] & 0xff));
        }
        counter++;
        if (counter == 128) {
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    totalByte += actualBytesRead;
}
```

Output:
[image]